# Convert Binary to File Using PHP

Tags: php, binaryfiles

I'm using a service that gives you a `wav` file. this service gives me base64 binary code as a result. I want to convert it to a wav file.

I've been googling for it and couldn't find anything. here is my code :

```
    $wsdl=' < url > ';//url to WSDL
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
    $param=array(
        'userName'=>' < my username> ',
        'password'=>' < my password > ',
        'messageId'=>1063716
    ); // parameters needed to download the file 
    try{
       $res=$client->DownloadMessage($param)    ;
       $base64Binary = $res->DownloadMessageResult;
       echo $base64Binary;
       }catch(Exception $e){
           echo '<pre>' ;
           var_dump($e->getMessage());
           echo '</pre>' ;
       }
```

and the result of the echo is this:

```
RIFF&WAVEfmt @€>dataÞ%¯ÿ@HrÿvÿÿâÿÂÿ7Æÿ‚ÿžÿ€ÿÎÿÌÿQQÝV…‚© K 6(Iv7%ýÿñÿÃÿªÿÐÿ¦ÿÜÿWÿKÿ®ÿ¯ÿÝÿ”ÿ•ÿwÿ¹ÿ¶\JŸœñ{KH66þÿõÿõÿäÿªÿDÚÿ÷ÿªÿìÿÒÿNóÿØÿÈÿÝÿÄÿÞÿžÿ'Úÿ¾ÿÒÿYÿqÿ…ÿÌÿ×ÿÃÿµÿ¸ÿÉÿÏÿñÿŸ‰¿uÚÿ$x;^UÁÿ¾ÿÅÿ|ÿ­ÿ¤ÿøÿüÿÿ™ÿèÿªÿmÿ…ÿAÿ™ÿŒÿ0ÿÿˆÿB•ùÿ·ÿ†™ðjÖ=1µê}*|!<ÿ‘ÿNÿ|ÿ¦ÿÿÿ¼þ,ÿ(ÿÖÿÿyÿÇÿÕÿÒÿîÿy 0TOHƒ-Q$’‰kO>\¾µÇÿ¥ÿØÿÿ(¸ÿÁÿŸÿ÷ÿêÿœÿõÿsÿ¤Ùÿ#ôÿƒÿ[Ÿâÿ›ÿÝÿ;§ÿ,ÕÿMK¾ÿ<�EÎÿŒÿ©ÿfÿ²ÿ²ÿ¢ÿ¿ÿªÿóÿ0aãÂ~T¬íq]/.D*áÿÿ•ÿ`ÿoÿsÿˆÿ<�.ßÿaÞ[‘•kùÿ ÿhÿ:ÿóþ0ÿWÿšÿêÿ1|N©ÿÊÿßÿýÿ¿ÿ¸ÿSÿÝÿúÿ)°ÿ‰ÿâÿwÿÙÿ^ÿ¼ÿ­ÿ®ÿÕÿhóÿ¶ÿôÿe)DãÿØœˆ=o]¨˜1+  J»+;çÿÍÿÔÿg¤ÿÚÿÿÓÿÿàÿÖÿÍÿ?ÖÿÖÿD oöÿ}ÿ—ÿaÿ¤ÿ¨ÿvÿ·ÿ1ÿ¼ÿ”ÿíÿˆÿ09#°ÿC¨ÿ: ?`%_îÿJ*[dBãÿQëÿïÿüÿïÿÐÿcÿ›ÿ¼ÿøÿÕÿÇÿäÿÜÿH«ÿ¹ÿèÿÉ$Î€aCMy2r3^ž<�ØÿHçÿ-†ÿŽÿ@ÿ%ÿBÿ‹ÿºÿ¡ÿ"éÿ÷ÿ«ÿçÿçÿ/öÿ¡ÿôÿ¸ÿõÿéÿrvgj%?²ÿÒÿÿöÿËÿ®ÿ‡ÿ<ÿ¼ÿ­ÿD1ŠcY+    Iuÿÿ04SÌÿ:<ÿXÿûþyÿFÿ÷ÿŒÿiÿÙÿŒÿòÿ¥ÿ  ÏÿðÿÑÿhO#Òý¼» ¶&1\ÿgÿžÿªÿœÿûÿ#þÿ3   µûy(E„ÿ/¥ÿŸÿŒÿ2ÿ!ÿúþ_ÿÈþ¾ÿ·ÿpÿŒÿ:ÿøÿÝÿæÿãÿ_–±œ2ë•òÚË•xøÿÛÿåÿªÿîÿÎÿÃÿIÿ\ÿj·ÿ·ÿcÿËÿ<�=6xQ„R„=…ÿdÿœÿMÿ ýÿ‚MÃ¼±PþÿžÿmÿƒÿNÿéÿ ÿOŒÿmÿVÿÿ$m›ûÿêÿ›ÿ2òþÕþvÿäÿþÿ{ÿûÿnÿ-Q\v[ÿÿ2ÿ!ÿ—þ´ÿDÿ8ÿ™ÿ*ÿäÿ)fJýŒ5hÈ3ÃJOVk/jÆ*<ˆv/\pÿÿçþ¨þ›þtþMþqþÀþIÿYÿBÿ¾ÿúÿB6t¥õßñÛ()¼ÿëk¢ÿj7“„ÿÿïÿýÿñÿ&ùÿÎÿcG¤ÿÈÿÀÿ²”ÿÞÿXÿ*ÿÿ,ÿ þ³þéþ¥¤wûÿq;æÿÿÀÿðÿEÇþ$ÿÿ­ÿ«ÆÿàÿŽÿwHUÿ1ÿvÿhÿ^ÿÿaþéþRÿÿµþÿ¡ÿÍÿrÿ„ÿaÿÀÿïÿ~ÿÃÿòÿ«TÓrb¿û‰ý¿Û}Iä|«}v¾o1Ñÿç;õÿûý<þzþ¾ýêüüü¿þ–\ÛÈé¤Z’%½ÿßý^ýÆýþdÿIž‚q_èˆ¶Á¾£þŸý°þdýêüÿ&Â¼:=o2ý;ÿ"þžþÖÈ^ÿü„û˜ýþbüWùø.úðû{üú…û¿šþö¹öòörùøØñô„üV¹¬ý&üôÙ¨û÷zü B¹ÿþŸÿœ¶}ÿóõàþŠþQô³â ºù7þ»ó0ý ýðä¡ÜåËôcÇ©è üÚõêÌî?öøò9òø‰°ö¶qÍÅmtî%¸|EùøÿFax¶/CÞÁ~ˆ(&&D(üKñ+÷OGëÔÖãlö‹úÁÿFö îåübî\ÞÐæNû³:T~4 ‰›þ%ä …ª¹ðÐîE_ÐûfúÑûýÞþ…ÿéÿÿLþIý ülüwüœý8þCz2…wÝý:O6'%êõÀè¿ñcû áSØÒï(¯]¢õ)ý÷|íáÚéIÿïb   =  Ëøºî9ð;úã   s‘›!ï†`&üvÿÌTGÔáÿriþÀü2ü2ýÊý`üü-ÿV Mÿ¬ürüàü]ý(üÿû°üÿ–¬ÿÿLÿ÷ÿÿ'þÿÿwþ÷åþkG;Æ%Ýÿ®ìóã<ô`tæÁØðI"n ùìëõ õéeÜgàe÷´8MRüÍ{ÿ&ïsæ[ó~þmH¸¤2™ÿîûœþw†o†ÕÒ×6¦ á±þñýõüîüÿ²ÿÿÑÿêÿþþÂþþ¡ýýký¶ýÚþŒÿ)·ÿhÿ“þÖþëýÿNþÍ?ÿøìþòE9€$¦þîièô¾ü}áùØHóaÅ lÊûŒö˜Åõžã¿Û$á^õ‘ÓT[›'0qîcèô}ÿ‹   Ks1T]åYÎþ¿þL‡mÎ¤<ÿ´ªaÿÊü±þ€a#ÿËü$þ¼È×ýðú9üÁþ¡þý}ý˜ÿ§Lÿþ´ý¡ÿ zËþÜÿÇÿ®FŠvÿißfe)¼0cDûJðÝïúþÎîÖÃæåvŠˆîö1>éí’Þ3ÛjêÂ« ÿ×þªöÃ Lù¸ì¬ñ YXÝ   ýuì­ VØÿ'i+[Èê?‘ÿiþºÿž=€0M*Î£þŠüöûÈüÙüAý~ý‘þ)ÿšÿ‰þÙý(ý!ýý"ý¼ýþÉÿÉÿ/dÿÎ´ýµ ,P"|ö¹þ7ýãÝtï:ýÊ  _ký÷ÿ" $Êñ_ç-æHðìøôÓò=ûõÆ[ücú×ÿåÐX[WdD MPsþÿ1{ñÔÃ¬#kf¦Sè@pÿ-ÿGµÿÃþÿmþœþþ¦ý0ýiý'ýý.ýâüŒýÃý&þ¯ýMþÄýºþQþ"ÿÕþÓÿÁÿ|½óŽ6!_ ?…amùØç‡ë%ñã÷×þ¦û´ú’‚Çÿ$úQò³ðó…ðOîÝñH÷0ý:ù@Ê ærúÕm Z6; tXÞóØ½eãªŽ§ÁÈb¸ò‘âð¡s'¾|ÿdþ|ýý“ünüVüšü­ü#ýDýŒý–ý¦ýŽýbýPýñü"ýÂüeý ý?þ¼ý¡ÿ—þÚÂóÆ ·TRÁÿèùø‡õŽðRï»ï¨îäñSó"ôöø¯ø"û½ûûÎûgû1ûJûûúËúPýÙþ­çÊ* º  BX!ó±Ç)#ƒÔ‚(fûµ%'öÀÿäþþ2ýœü/ü˜ûwû;û+û+ûNûWû†ûËûàûWüküý ýðýÏýùþ¹þÿpQÃÃ¬ £¡Ž x]ÚÿÞûÿõãñ÷îÛê[ëSëçêÅìï=ñnõ¤ø¼úCýÿ ^Ò[uI£H}ÖY;÷ ØÇ —æ£5» bãFÂEŽ¼$ÿCþ8ýEüûâú_úBúúMúyúûQû.ügü:ýpý!þ@þÕþìþOÿ§ÿbžÁ\í Ñ~CË[7fúµõIò'íåëRëvé„êìÍíSñ‡õÕ÷ûüýXÿW°¨Ôùäë=é”ãÞ²Ägwï4,Ø·   3¬å-¬I G ÀÖ6<®ÿïý)ülúRùFø!÷ìöÓö®ö'÷[÷Ê÷2ø!ù)ù8úFúOûwûãüàü‰þÅþBÞ…rÂ~~ƒÇÙýGù¢õšìOè`ç×ã/çì¥ì+ñýõ‘ø>üVÿ2ý?üûõø"øBö õáörúþþ8ÓèQ…€îO¥Q×ó»:Íà$ ½_²ps  èh³þý´üžüÛû%ü0üàûqûæúîøØ÷iöäô÷ó$ó®ò›ò&ôkôA÷øKûü´ÿŽÿ“" HÉKlç0”hú²ôåêðìºèÞîÚòÎóâ)ø¥³Éù•ùiô|éõæäUáÝèÔîô h       r5`Ë‰)ãû‹Üu¯d- šo4þj!   Æþ ¥áýÅýñýþü¹üsü<ûUú@úø2÷ÅõÓôÍóËôØó5õ›õ7÷dø©úüJý}ÿNÿžn/ü^šº!øÙ K    møMõ­æoßëíæõ…ü ÿ(ÿ• i]Zò4êé=äá‚åä+ëY÷úÓo-:g!obÆ¶ bÚÍªÚù‰uÄ.G—ó¹6ÛÃ˜©ÄíT¡ÿtþ·ýåýüIûYùZøAø*ùIù¿ù¨ùµùSú]ûÜû5üüBüªý¹ýÙÿöþžKÿ€Mÿ…n% "=)ƒ8û÷8îÝéxåú×]ãÛïYlÇã6+úáõêýÜ°×±ÙaâØïXü°§€rAoÐõ¹   ‹a ¯7‰t‡¥ Ä rŽ®‡)qÔÿÍþeþ/2ÿÉþtýÐû2ûû%ü­ûaüûîûküþ-þÿþþþ‡þQÿcÿùþÒ+ÿÕòþÿÈ$u&¥(ç öû$ìœê‚å2êÃäTßòêª÷àÌ ÐþmóTì|ìŒæàWÝ^ãîDÿÙ…•š˜™Blä„ØŽ—%x\é’‚D20G³Ó“Â"‹ÐKŽr~»FR±,yÿçüýGû‘û”übü:ýæü†ýëü&þ£ý»ýtýýüý`ý{þ‹þNÿ¾Ïÿ +Mÿgà#Ò$À*2ïüòéRáSã"éŽîëéQïï÷ß|^#7þ ìßøà7åJèêëùñ¾ÿ‘—M,,Gybàæ[Ï?ö ÊAøÿ úÿ-0K›ôæN³»ú—ýÿ^ÿ%r|¸ÿ#ÿÆý'üeû7úJûªû£ý6ÿ’¢ÿïþ\þËýûýþðþIÿî×QSêÿáHþâ "4%»*ùýáÖ`ß³ê¼øbùú5úïîèú€älÕbÖ,äXöËI†F±êe¨þ6[   3l î)ô¬+ËCýÿ÷ÿùÿøÿ*3OeÐþ‘˜eÖt°´È3Êÿý¤ýSÿ§þ¾ÿfýðü!üHüªýTýBýVü”úÌúüÜýÿ–ÿÓþÈý–þmÿPÞÌÿxƒ»=c ¸"“&Lîý+æOÜÂäüíú·ýþ-ü_þž®/ö-ëãåJíþ÷}ß3ýþ—UÒÆ    › Ž]p}Â…Ã‘’ZBÿÿõÿõÿõÿøÿûÿÿÿ/N–×lÃÖìwi>„%}ÿÿ‘ýÌü«üüüƒý0üoü³ú]úDúZúºûwüƒýìýsþaþÜþ”þ’ÿmÿ,$ø    Ü­Nü¬²é9    QýÉîÝðäòøðùnúø¡öTøú¥ý)û”÷ƒñzí™íßðj÷Åü.þáýÔüùü}ÿÉ É 1lº”Ì Ô §”‰ƒÎ…I6 øÿöÿþÿ÷ÿþÿ÷ÿúÿ3S¢ê Œr‹r­uBqíÿ×ÿ*ÿšþ¼ýšý.ýý ý´üeüüäûÊûyüÙûýNýdþÿ’ÿ{!¿n ed–„ü}m YÙüª÷+ø›÷]úáøiù*ö¬öìöù<ûù®÷!óñ+ñó.÷ƒù$ûrû4üÖýúo©– Ž ¸ú Oê¹s’ ˜V%ýÿþÿøÿúÿöÿùÿõÿøÿöÿûÿûÿ'LËEâ©·›K›qþÛ:Ë÷×g¾ÿÅþ^þ/þØýƒý¡ü>ü¢û—ûžû#üŠüÖüý%ýuý¶ý;þµþ0ÿaÿÁÿ±ÿ3ùwÙuç^ ßÄ IH®îÿRýû¤÷cöÛõ¤õRöØöD÷Fö¡õÿô!õ  öG÷YøÅøþùðúÏû±ý°ÿÓIÓÈ   ž‘ £=JÇt@"þÿûÿúÿøÿ÷ÿöÿöÿôÿôÿöÿùÿ7k°7÷ÇÅÝ•¥›Ð‹Ü”oó3‘èT²ÿøþ}þ¸ý'ý üzügüLübügüœü«üýCý¦ýõýUþ„þ½þïþ5ÿkÿýÿ3à»dl«œ¾`Å3vþýû¿ùrøo÷’õ-ô¡ó˜ó3ôÛôfõÖõªö¯÷“ø²ùû²ü¦þ¯TªÚ¸ƒ¥—¿)ÂzN/ýÿüÿúÿùÿøÿ÷ÿöÿõÿ÷ÿýÿ@}ÍDâråDmqb/Þ~$Êc©T#úÿ°ÿ™ÿ¡ÿ“ÿ£ÿ¤ÿvÿfÿ^ÿCÿ?ÿ;ÿ%ÿÿÿõþýþÿ+ÿ9ÿcÿ|ÿÜÿøÖäÏ~U o·ö…·3áÿÿ«ýˆü©û®ú’ù×ørø4øJøUø…øÌø:ùÁùJúûÆû—ü¹ýíþâÿßÝ…ÝØvñsº~T6$ÿÿÿÿþÿþÿÿÿþÿýÿýÿüÿþÿ#:PaixŒ‡yreSKH>22*   ýÿõÿíÿæÿÜÿÒÿÎÿÕÿÜÿ×ÿÙÿÞÿåÿêÿöÿ÷ÿøÿ6m@ÏûeÜ.„w    íuõ¿o   ÑŠ*ñÿÚÿ§ÿrÿ[ÿ/ÿ ÿÿãþ¤þ†þ€þwþ€þªþÕþÿNÿÿ·ÿ×ÿ6a€ï9ŸÕ³¯ÆT)¥¯ÿ„ÿQÿÿòþwþþþ(þQþ•þØþõþ¬þˆþšþNþþñýoý]ýõýrþÓþ!ÿ*ÿ"ÿ/ÿ4ÿBÿKÿ<ÿ!ÿÿÿúþÿþKÿ›ÿ«ÿ›ÿ¬ÿÙÿ×ÿÈÿêÿèÿÅÿÔÿÚÿ®ÿÿƒÿqÿ¥ÿh ¿ÐÕñßŽNÙÿžÿÿaÿXÿ[ÿ?ÿ>ÿUÿPÿKÿFÿ:ÿMÿ–ÿÏÿÕÿüÿI…™™~aKH3ïÿ¦ÿ˜ÿ¨ÿšÿ‚ÿdÿOÿDÿIÿ=ÿ2ÿDÿ]ÿmÿyÿÿ{ÿ”ÿ½ÿÌÿÀÿ½ÿ¾ÿÐÿñÿûÿáÿ¾ÿ©ÿ¤ÿ©ÿ¢ÿ˜ÿžÿºÿÊÿËÿÑÿàÿúÿ#&%+I]f{–«¦”~zuaG5/-÷ÿíÿæÿÔÿ¾ÿ­ÿ›ÿÿŠÿ–ÿ¤ÿ°ÿ®ÿ«ÿ®ÿ²ÿÂÿÃÿÃÿÅÿµÿ¬ÿ¡ÿŒÿÿ›ÿ¡ÿ›ÿ’ÿÿžÿ°ÿ¶ÿÇÿÒÿÜÿêÿýÿüÿ!" ÷ÿ÷ÿýÿóÿëÿîÿèÿßÿÞÿÌÿÀÿÇÿÀÿ½ÿÊÿÕÿÕÿØÿÕÿÕÿÕÿØÿãÿãÿáÿÝÿæÿ÷ÿ   (28<�AGJOPV\]WXVUTD846;1&"ôÿæÿïÿøÿÿÿÿÿõÿìÿçÿïÿ÷ÿñÿèÿäÿèÿèÿÝÿËÿÑÿÛÿÜÿçÿêÿöÿ'75486% *.$ìÿÔÿÁÿ»ÿ¸ÿ¸ÿÀÿÈÿ×ÿáÿðÿüÿýÿ    þÿþÿúÿïÿèÿïÿðÿêÿíÿñÿðÿñÿóÿïÿùÿ-@D7.öÿíÿéÿåÿêÿíÿàÿåÿñÿúÿ #),-7AB:.($! þÿóÿéÿïÿîÿíÿõÿÿÿúÿõÿðÿéÿæÿäÿèÿëÿïÿéÿçÿãÿßÿïÿîÿèÿìÿñÿôÿõÿñÿòÿïÿíÿîÿìÿòÿÿÿûÿûÿ  ÿÿòÿüÿ   þÿüÿùÿüÿÿÿùÿöÿöÿòÿïÿæÿáÿÞÿÜÿàÿéÿïÿúÿ ÿÿ õÿõÿóÿñÿíÿíÿõÿøÿ    ùÿöÿúÿ "&ýÿüÿþÿÿÿüÿúÿùÿ÷ÿòÿëÿóÿ÷ÿûÿøÿñÿîÿðÿóÿòÿåÿêÿñÿñÿùÿûÿÿÿÿÿùÿÿÿùÿúÿ ÿÿ÷ÿîÿìÿïÿôÿúÿñÿìÿñÿòÿéÿëÿóÿòÿçÿâÿèÿèÿñÿþÿ  þÿüÿóÿìÿçÿðÿ÷ÿ   øÿêÿßÿßÿåÿìÿòÿîÿùÿ$   üÿúÿ÷ÿõÿüÿûÿþÿýÿúÿüÿøÿùÿÿÿúÿýÿüÿõÿðÿêÿêÿíÿíÿëÿðÿóÿñÿñÿôÿôÿïÿîÿïÿøÿ       ñÿïÿéÿñÿþÿ÷ÿþÿþÿûÿûÿúÿûÿüÿüÿóÿóÿæÿçÿïÿøÿüÿûÿ ÿÿüÿûÿøÿîÿñÿóÿôÿýÿúÿûÿÿÿûÿýÿ   þÿñÿóÿùÿ÷ÿðÿèÿàÿãÿæÿæÿðÿøÿöÿ÷ÿ  ÿÿûÿôÿéÿâÿÛÿØÿÜÿÞÿãÿíÿóÿøÿùÿøÿýÿÿÿûÿöÿüÿ ÿÿùÿ÷ÿüÿ!!     üÿþÿ    þÿúÿíÿéÿíÿìÿïÿðÿïÿòÿóÿ÷ÿúÿýÿ%'" ÿÿûÿùÿðÿîÿðÿêÿçÿèÿéÿïÿíÿòÿòÿòÿñÿëÿðÿîÿòÿúÿ  ÿÿýÿûÿ÷ÿîÿîÿòÿüÿÿÿ  ÿÿýÿûÿøÿõÿîÿèÿèÿâÿØÿ×ÿÚÿÝÿàÿæÿëÿîÿòÿõÿûÿÿÿ  üÿõÿòÿéÿéÿêÿëÿëÿêÿëÿëÿâÿâÿâÿáÿêÿçÿèÿéÿîÿïÿ÷ÿÿÿ      ûÿõÿúÿùÿøÿôÿõÿóÿôÿøÿøÿûÿúÿøÿøÿúÿýÿÿÿ     ÿÿúÿøÿüÿúÿòÿõÿøÿüÿþÿ    úÿþÿüÿüÿüÿõÿóÿðÿëÿãÿÞÿâÿàÿåÿæÿåÿéÿóÿüÿ    ýÿùÿùÿïÿêÿêÿèÿçÿçÿçÿëÿïÿòÿôÿòÿòÿïÿïÿñÿöÿüÿýÿÿÿÿÿþÿ÷ÿóÿñÿòÿðÿïÿðÿîÿîÿðÿõÿñÿõÿúÿûÿúÿ÷ÿøÿõÿôÿóÿ÷ÿøÿ! ÿÿüÿüÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿüÿýÿþÿÿÿþÿþÿùÿóÿóÿóÿöÿöÿóÿëÿìÿìÿéÿîÿõÿ÷ÿöÿùÿ÷ÿ÷ÿûÿþÿýÿ þÿüÿúÿøÿ÷ÿöÿôÿôÿñÿòÿóÿùÿøÿøÿüÿöÿûÿ        ÿÿúÿõÿöÿ÷ÿùÿöÿøÿôÿìÿäÿçÿæÿèÿïÿêÿíÿñÿ÷ÿúÿÿÿÿÿ÷ÿøÿúÿýÿ""'%!    üÿöÿôÿôÿöÿôÿûÿûÿýÿ
```

is this a base 64 binary? if it is, how to convert it to a wav file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you're echoing looks like a plain wav stream. Just write it to a file without any decoding and you'll end up with a wav file. Be sure to use binary mode when writing the file.

```
$ptr = fopen("file.wav", 'wb');
fwrite($ptr, $e->getMessage());
fclose($ptr);
```

Wav header info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#RIFF_WAVE

Answer (score 1):

If the base64 encoded data already represents an MP3 file, it should be as easy as decoding the base64 data and storing it in a file:

```
file_put_contents('audio.mp3', base64_decode($base64Binary));
```

Comment: is it normal to have the RIFF&WAVEfmt in front of the string?